# ASP.Net web app works locally but after I publish to Azure app service I get 404 on all web requests

Tags: asp.net, azure

I created a very simple ASP.NET web app, It works when I run it locally out of Visual Studio.  When I publish through Visual Studio the HTML and JS functions as expected but when I try and make a request it will only return a 404 with a sub HTTP status of 0.  I found the failed requests in the log in the Azure portal but it gives me nothing helpful (Maybe I don't know what I should be looking for).

JS request:

```
var mainURL = "api/values";
function getData() {
    $.ajax(mainURL + "",
        {
            method: "GET",
            success: getFeedback,
            error: error
        });
}
```

GET endpoint in ValuesController.cs:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
     return new String[] { "String 1", "String 2"};
}
```

Heres what I get in the log for each failed request:

```
timestamp [UTC]:  2019-06-14T18:37:28.4905616Z
id:-  |t6BRs.GIk+K.5d5a779d_
name:-  GET Values/Get
url:-  https://snowcrew.azurewebsites.net/api/values
success:-  False
resultCode:-  404
duration:-  26,036.3695
performanceBucket:-  15sec-30sec
itemType:-  request
customDimensions:-  {"_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Requests',Ver:'1.1')","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Production"}
operation_Name:-  GET Values/Get
operation_Id:-  t6BRs
operation_ParentId:-  |t6BRs.GIk+K
session_Id:-  Weaja
user_Id:-  /2aXn
application_Version:-  1.0.0.0
client_Type:-  PC
client_IP:-  0.0.0.0
client_City:-  MyCity
client_StateOrProvince:-  MyState
client_CountryOrRegion:-  United States
cloud_RoleName:-  snowcrew
cloud_RoleInstance:-  RD0004FFDD7879
appId:-  9114c348-64a5-4490-8c37-7c469252ba2a
appName:-  SnowCrew
iKey:-  55a1c3de-a678-49af-9fcb-9212758047fb
sdkVersion:-  ar_aspnet5c:2.6.1
itemId:-  97b165e2-8ed3-11e9-905b-5feb1a1b3fb1
itemCount:-  1
```

Comment: Can you show us the entire ValuesController, Startup.cs and Program.cs?

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin What we expect to be in StartUp.cs and Program.cs if our app has enabled Application Insight in Azure Portal?